# Can't "wget" a link after passing a captcha

Tags: terminal, wget, captcha

Normally, after passing the captcha, I can copy&paste the link of the protected resource (e.g. video) and download with "wget" on the terminal.

Sth. weird happens to this website: (download raw video footage)
http://download.iris32.com/clip/H058_C003_0320O5.html

After captcha, I find the link to the video ends with ".html". If I open it on current browser, it starts to download; if on other browsers or wget, it only gets the captcha webpage.

So, what trick are they using? Is there a way to download the video with "wget"?

Thanks

Comment: Does they ask for captcha every next videos?

Comment: yes. one captcha for each video